# How to render links with weasyprint?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, pdf-generation, weasyprint

```
from weasyprint import HTML
HTML(string='<a href="http://google.com">link</a>').write_pdf('tmp.pdf')
```

Doesn't have clickable link inside it.

I'm scraping a part of the site as HTML and tryting to render that part. Maybe that is the problem. But I don't have full valid HTML. Does it mean that I can't render proper PDF using weasyprint?

The above example will have clickable link using xhtml2pdf. Is there any way to make it work with weasyprint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in WeasyPrint 0.17 and possibly some previous versions. See https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/42